# Parsing CSV file with dynamic separator

Tags: context-free-grammar, rascal

I try to solve the following parsing problem, but I fail:

I have a CSV file that with a certain command inside the file can change separators, and the current separator can be escaped with a slash. Look at this example:

```
a,b,c,list;with;values
a,b,c,list\,with\,values
@separator,;
a;b;c;list,with,values
a;b;c;list\;with\;values
```

Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to have a grammar with context. Rascal only supports context free grammars.

The format seems simple enough, couldn't a loop with some context variables solve this? (In any language that has basic string operations)

Comment: Too bad I don't get an IDE for free that way.

Comment: Sure you do. All you have to do is have a function which produces a `Tree`. It does not have to be a generated parser. It can be a composition of generated parsers or something that produces a `Tree` in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the CSV reader in `lang::csv::IO` which deals with these exceptions if I'm not mistaken.

If you want to write a grammar for this, you can use a parametrized non-terminals (I guess) to instantiate a new grammar for every new separator you use, or have a different grammar for every separator. You then first split the file on `@separator` and then parse the different pieces with each different grammar.

Comment: The "standard" does not allow escaping a char in this way, it states that quotes should be used for escaping newlines and separators.

Our csv library follows this standard.